# ElasticSearch Nested query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Имеется индекс эластика со структурой

```
{"idx_nested":
    {"aliases":{},
        "mappings":{"idx":
            {"properties":
                {
                    "country":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
                    "delete_date":{"type":"date"},
                    "id":{"type":"long"},
                    "keyList":{"type":"nested"},
                    "reasons":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В keyList загружается структура вида "person" : person_name.

При запросе через REST или Postman, используя JSON:

```
{
     "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "keyList",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "match": { "keyList.person": "John" }},
                            { "match": { "keyList.person": "Smith" }}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

все прекрасно работает. Пытаюсь сделать то же  самое с помощью Nest:

```
var res = await client.SearchAsync<myobj>(c => c.Query(x=>x.
                                            Nested(xx=>xx
                                                    .Path("keyList")
                                                        .Query(q=>q
                                                            .Bool(bq=>bq
                                                                .Must(new Nest.MatchQuery
                                                                            {
                                                                                Field = "keyList.person",
                                                                                Query = "John"
                                                                            } 
                                                               )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
```

получаю ошибку:

```
 Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path
 'hits.hits[0]._source.keyList', line 7, position 5.
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 0):

Сам дурак. Неверно был описан объект "myobj"

При записи в индекс использовался объект myobj1, а при поиске через NEST - myobj. Он, а точнее, Newtonsoft.Json ругался на несовпадение объектов.

Comment: Опишите, как этот объект должен выглядеть.

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте более развернутые ответы, они могут оказаться полезными другим посетителям.

Comment: Просто при  записи в индекс использовался объект myobj1, а при поиске через NEST  - myobj.  Он, а точнее, Newtonsoft.Json ругался на несовпадение объектов.